# SettingWithCopyWarning on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

The line

```
res2.loc[: , other_column_name] = res2.loc[: , other_column_name].apply(np.log)
```

,where `res2` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, gives the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

After several attempts, I have been able to get rid of the warning by rewriting the line into this

```
res3 = res2.copy()
log = res2.loc[: , other_column_name].apply(np.log) 
res3.loc[: , other_column_name] = log
```

This is clearly not an elegant solution, is there any better way to solve this?

**EDIT 1**

`res2`  was created this way:

```
res2 = res1[res1.index <= last_valid_sentiment]
```

also

```
res2.head()

        sentiment  inf_neg
2001-11-28  -2.856371      0.534482
2001-12-26  -2.023266      0.473392
2002-01-30  -1.505361      0.444845
2002-02-27  -2.121079      0.433922
2002-03-27  -1.692547      0.469621
```

Comment: Ignore the warning/turn it off? It's well-known that it throws false positives. I'm not convinced that `res2.loc[: , other_column_name].apply(np.log) ` is an issue, but you could take the `values` to be sure

Comment: it all depends on how you construct res2, can you show us the code?

Comment: Actually, I'm confused. `res2[column_name] = np.log(res2[column_name])`?